# knockout trim in mvvm validations

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I am using knockout as mvvm it works fine but i don't want to send data containing white spaces to server side code. Here is my sample code

```
   //Regular Customer
    self.nameForRegularCustomer = ko.observable("").extend({
        required: { message: 'Promotion Name is required' },
        maxlength: {
            message: 'Promotion Name can not exceed 100 character',
            params: '100'
        }
    });
    self.statusForRegularCustomer = 1; //For create Mode always  1 as new
    self.keywordForRegularCustomer = ko.observable("").extend({
        required: { message: 'Keyword is required' },
        maxlength: {
            message: 'Keyword can not exceed 100 character',
            params: '100'
        }
    });
    self.promotionMsgForRegularCustomer = ko.observable("").extend({
        required: { message: 'Promotion Message is required' }
    });
    self.promotionDescForRegularCustomer = ko.observable("").extend({
        required: { message: 'Promotion Description is required' }
        , maxlength: {
            message: 'Description can not exceed 100 character',
            params: '2000'
        }
    });
    //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
    self.RegularCustomerPromotion = {
        name: self.nameForRegularCustomer,
        description: self.promotionDescForRegularCustomer,
        keywords: self.keywordForRegularCustomer,
        happyMessage: self.promotionMsgForRegularCustomer,
        status: self.statusForRegularCustomer,
        promotionCustomerType: self.promotionCustomerType
    };
```

I am making ajax call with folllowing data format

```
  requestPromo = ko.toJSON(self.NewCustomerPromotion);
```

but this contains data with white space also i want to trim it before making API call
 I tried to use for field level

```
 ko.subscribable.fn.trimmed = function () {
   return ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this().trim();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        this(value.trim());
       // this.valueHasMutated();
    },
    owner: this
});
```

but this discards validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your own toJSON method on your view-model and strip out the unnecessary white-space yourself.  knockout has two functions toJS and toJSON.  you can use toJS to get the current values as a javascript Object or use toJSON to get the string representation.

This is just off the top of my head and i'm not sure if it works but something like this.

```
self.prototype.toJSON = function(){
  var data = ko.toJS(self.NewCustomerPromotion);

  return {
        name: data.nameForRegularCustomer.trim(),
        description: data.promotionDescForRegularCustomer.trim(),
        keywords: data.keywordForRegularCustomer.trim(),
        happyMessage: data.promotionMsgForRegularCustomer.trim(),
        status: data.statusForRegularCustomer.trim(),
        promotionCustomerType: data.promotionCustomerType.trim()
    };
};
```

This will return an object that is ready to be serialized with the ko.toJSON to be sent over the wire.

Here is a blog post explaining in greater detail http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html

Comment: thanks  i used this but some what different way  using following

Answer (score 0):

```
 function removeSpace(object) {

var copy = ko.toJS(object); //easy way to get a clean copy
for (var property in object) {
    if (typeof (object[property]) == "function" && property != "errors" && property != "isValid" && property != "isAnyMessageShown") {
        copy[property] = object[property]().trim();
    }
}
return copy;
 };
```